# Blur gradient in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a circular div with the following css:

```
z-index: 9999;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
pointer-events: none;

backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

How can I add an (opacity?) gradient to this div to make the blur end less abruptly
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blur-mask {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(50% - 75px);
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<h1>LOREM</h1>
<div class="blur-mask"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mask the blur using mask-image and a radial gradient

```
mask-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```